# How to change the date_add interval type dependant of a field in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ofbiz

Imagine the following table (it has other rows but the ones shown below being used in the query),

```
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+ 
| INTERVAL_QUANTITY | INTERVAL_UOM_ID | LAST_UPDATED_STAMP  |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+ 
| 10                | TF_wk           | 2017-10-31 17:21:40 |
| 20                | TF_mon          | 2017-10-30 17:21:40 | 
| 30                | TF_day          | 2017-10-29 17:21:40 |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

**Key**

- TF_wk => WEEK
- TF_mon => MONTH
- TF_day => DAY

Now, I have the following query,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    product_maint 
WHERE
    ( INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_day' OR INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_wk' OR INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_mon' ) 
    AND DATEDIFF( DATE( DATE_ADD( LAST_UPDATED_STAMP, INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY DAY ) ), DATE( NOW( ) ) ) <= 0;
```

The issue is, when it selects a row which has a `INTERVAL_UOM_ID` of `TF_wk` and `INTERVAL_QUANTITY` of `10` it actually needs to add on `70` days not `10` days, likewise when the `INTERVAL_UOM_ID` is `TF_mon` and the `INTERVAL_QUANTITY` is `20` it needs to add on `560` days (assuming all my math is correct).

How would I go about implementing this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check each interval separately.  I think you want:

```
WHERE ( INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_day' AND
        LAST_UPDATED_STAMP > CURDATE() - INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY DAY 
      ) OR
      ( INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_wk' AND 
        LAST_UPDATED_STAMP > CURDATE() - INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY WEEK 
      ) OR
      ( INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_mon' AND
        LAST_UPDATED_STAMP > CURDATE() - INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY MONTH 
      )
```

Note that I changed the `NOW()` to `CURDATE()`.  I don't think the time component is important for what you want to do.  Also note that I changed the logic to work only with date arithmetic.

Comment: It seems for some reason using the above query, it shows all the rows, the logic is broken somewhere, any ideas?

Comment: Using your logic of combining the `TF_*` check with the DATE check worked for me when I used my comparison method. So basically: `SELECT
 * 
FROM
 product_maint 
WHERE
 (INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_day' 
 AND DATEDIFF ( DATE( DATE_ADD( LAST_UPDATED_STAMP, INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY DAY)), DATE( NOW( ))) <= 0 ) OR (
 INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_wk' 
 AND DATEDIFF ( DATE_ADD(DATE(  LAST_UPDATED_STAMP), INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY WEEK), DATE( NOW( ))) <= 0 ) OR (INTERVAL_UOM_ID = 'TF_mon' 
 AND DATEDIFF ( DATE( DATE_ADD( LAST_UPDATED_STAMP, INTERVAL INTERVAL_QUANTITY MONTH)), DATE( NOW( ))) <= 0 );`